# Use wget in shell script to test connectivity

Tags: shell, wget

I have a list of URLs in `urls.txt` that I want to test connectivity to from a server.

urls.txt:

```
www.google.com
www.yahoo.com
www.gmail.com
https://stackoverflow.com/questions
```

I want to run a simple shell script to test connectivity for each URL, and write the output of wget to a file `wget.log`
I also need to turn off downloads using `--spider`

This is my script:

```
urls=( $(awk '/URLs:/{y=1;next}y' urls.txt) )

for url in "${urls[@]}"
do
    wget --spider -o wget.log "${url}"
    if [ grep -q 'connected' wget.log ]; then
            echo 'successful'
    else
            echo 'unsuccessful'
    fi
    rm wget.log
done
```

The `for` loop works in that it stores each URL properly in the variable `url` but I am getting the following error: `line 6: [: too many arguments`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `[ ... ]` in your `if` statement, just use

```
...
if grep -q 'connected' wget.log; then
...
```

That way the `if` statement looks at the return value of `grep`.